# How does spring recognize the param inside a constructor

Tags: java, spring

I was trying to configure promethues in my code and I just had to create a bean like below. I was wondering how spring recognised `CollectorRegistry`. How did spring instantiate all the necessary variable for `CollectorRegistry` and setup all the necessary cofnfiguration?

```
@Component
public class TestProm{

 public TestProm(CollectorRegistry registry){ 
  // Some initialization code here
 }
}
```

However, when I tried to define it in another way by defining a `@Bean` in my `@Configuration` class, it didn't seem to work properly as my own constructor for `CollectorRegistry` didn't have all the necessary properties.

```
@Configuration
public class PromConfiguration{

@Bean
public TestProm getTestProm() {
 return new TestProm(new CollectorRegistry());
}

}



public class TestProm{
 public TestProm(CollectorRegistry registry){ 
 //Some code here
}
}
```

How do I recognise/replicate the initialization of `CollectorRegistry` done by spring when I do my custome implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How did spring instantiate all the necessary variable for CollectorRegistry and setup all the necessary cofnfiguration?

In the first example you require a Bean of type `CollectorRegistry` and Spring will actually create such bean for you if you have [`spring-boot-starter-actuator`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator) and Prometheus dependencies on your classpath and you have autoconfiguration enabled :

- if you use [`@EnableAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html)
- if you are using Spring Boot and [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) annotation (`@EnableAutoConfiguration` is part of this annotation underneath) :

```
...
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @ConfigurationPropertiesScan
...
public @interface SpringBootApplication
```

In this case Spring will scan the classpath and load all configurations. The bean that you are interested in is part of [`PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.html) :

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public CollectorRegistry collectorRegistry() {
    return new CollectorRegistry(true);
}
```

In the second example the instance of [`CollectorRegistry`](https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/io/prometheus/client/CollectorRegistry.html) is not managed by Spring because you create it through `new` keyword. However it should work as `CollectorRegistry` has default constructor which initializes `autoDescribe` field to `false`. And the default Bean of this class which is created by Spring (in a way described above) has this field set to `true`. So the value of this field is the source of your differences.

Also if this instance is not managed by Spring - it prevents it to be injected into other components which require it. As the scope of `CollectorRegistry` is Singleton (shown above) other beans might require to share the instance to work properly (for example some beans might want to register/deregister collectors) but if you create `CollectorRegistry` like that with `new` keyword - **you will not get the singleton instance but a new instance which cannot be shared across other beans**.

> 2. How do I recognise/replicate the initialization of CollectorRegistry done by spring when I do my custom implementation?

If you want to use the default `CollectorRegistry` (assuming you want to use the bean that is created by default in the way described above) just inject bean of this type to your beans and it should be enough.

Comment: The instantiation of CollectorRegistry doesn’t work by default with the new keyword. Is this because spring  prevents it to be injected into other components which require it. Is there a way around this? I’m asking out of curiosity. I will anyway let spring do it by itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What error do you receive?

Comment: Just that the counter that i configured is not visible in the Prometheus metrics. If i go with the spring configuration, it works just fine.